# Restrict Users From Creating Queries On Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to stop stakeholders or users from a particular group from creating their own queries and only allowing them to run shared queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation,

> All users can create and edit their own queries and save them under My Queries.

From the security chart for queries:

[image: Query default security]

It appears that the only way to restrict this is to remove your stakeholders from the Contributors group and add them to the Readers group, which is probably too restrictive for you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, I am afraid that there is no such method could restrict users from creating My Queries.

According to [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/set-query-permissions?view=azure-devops):

> All users can create and edit their own queries and save them under My Queries. Only you can view queries saved under your My Queries space.

[image]

First of all, the stakeholder role is the necessary permission to **access the organization** (the lowest).

This role still has the permission to create anad save My Queries.

Based on my test, when adding a stakeholder role user to the Project Readers Group, the user still could have permission to create query to My Query.

On the other hand, I suggest that you could create a suggestion tikcet in [Our UserVoice Site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) to report this feature.